# using XMLHttpRequest to get a web page but only get one part of the html

Tags: javascript

I use the code below to get a web page(html)

```
var  htmlString=null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.yahoo.com");//can change to any web address 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

     htmlString=htmlString+xhr.responseText;
     if(xhr.statusText=="200 OK\r" ){ 
       log (global.htmlString.length);
     }
}
```

but it always get one part of the page, rather than whole html code
Is there any parameter to set the length of the return html code?

Your comment welcome

Comment: can you share what you're receiving and what you think you should be receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be multiple `readystatechange` events. The request will only be completely done when `xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE === 4`.

Also, `htmlString = null; ...; htmlString=htmlString+xhr.responseText;` is bogus in many ways. First time around it will do `htmlString = null + "text" === "nulltext`. Afterwards it will add `.responseText` (as retrieved so far) again and again, while going through the states.

Also, on a related note, you should check `xhr.status == 200`, not `xhr.statusText == randomString`. Web servers aren't necessarily sending "OK" in case of 200.

Read the [`XMLHttpRequest` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Something like this should work better:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.yahoo.com");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 /* DONE */) {
     console.log(xhr.responseText.length);
     // Do something with it...
  }
}
xhr.send();
```